# PHP Warning: require_once Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, connection, laravel-artisan

first of all im new to laravel,

second i cloned a project from GitHub

I'm trying to start my laravel development server with| **php artisan serve** but it gives me this error:

```
 php artisan serve
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Sun Nov 27 08:38:27 2022] PHP 8.1.13 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
[Sun Nov 27 08:38:36 2022] 127.0.0.1:42986 Accepted
[Sun Nov 27 08:38:36 2022] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/amazy-ecommerce/public/index.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/amazy-ecommerce/server.php on line 21
[Sun Nov 27 08:38:36 2022] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/amazy-ecommerce/public/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/amazy-ecommerce/server.php:21
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/amazy-ecommerce/server.php on line 21
[Sun Nov 27 08:38:36 2022] 127.0.0.1:42986 Closing
[Sun Nov 27 08:38:36 2022] 127.0.0.1:42992 Accepted
[Sun Nov 27 08:38:36 2022] 127.0.0.1:43000 Accepted
[Sun Nov 27 08:38:47 2022] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/amazy-ecommerce/public/index.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/amazy-ecommerce/server.php on line 21
[Sun Nov 27 08:38:47 2022] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/amazy-ecommerce/public/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/amazy-ecommerce/server.php:21
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/amazy-ecommerce/server.php on line 21
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////

In bootstrap/App.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The first thing we will do is create a new Laravel application instance
| which serves as the "glue" for all the components of Laravel, and is
| the IoC container for the system binding all of the various parts.
|
*/

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Bind Important Interfaces
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we need to bind some important interfaces into the container so
| we will be able to resolve them when needed. The kernels serve the
| incoming requests to this application from both the web and CLI.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Return The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This script returns the application instance. The instance is given to
| the calling script so we can separate the building of the instances
| from the actual running of the application and sending responses.
|
*/

return $app;
```

/////////////////////////////////////

in server.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

in index.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check If Application Is Under Maintenance
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the application is maintenance / demo mode via the "down" command we
| will require this file so that any prerendered template can be shown
| instead of starting the framework, which could cause an exception.
|
*/

if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require __DIR__.'/storage/framework/maintenance.php';
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = tap($kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
))->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

And in the browser it say :

This page isn’t working

127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 500

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Like i said, I'm new to laravel, i didn't do much but i tried to read some similar issues but didn't find any solution to this problem since i don't understand it and  I'm kind of confused and don't want to mess it up.

so please help!

Comment: *'second i cloned a project from GitHub'* Is the project public? If so, please, share the Github URL link.

Comment: What Laravel framework version does the project use?

Comment: Could you share the **full** error stack trace? *'include_path='.:/usr/share/php'* This seems suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because you didn't install the dependencies.

Run `composer install` from the project root directory if you really didn't do it and run `php artisan serve` again

Answer (score 0):

if you didn't install composer then .

```
php artisan composer install
```

If you already installled

```
php artisan composer update
```

then ,

```
php artisan config:cache
```