# PHP Warning: require_once

Tags: php, laravel

I'M Trying to run a cloned project and set my php evironment but everytime i try to execute php artisan serve commad,it gives me this error... the problem is that im new to laravel...

```
almando@almando-ThinkPad-Edge-E531:~/Documents/laravelPro/active-ecommerce$ php artisan serve
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000


[Mon Dec 19 00:16:03 2022] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/active-ecommerce/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/active-ecommerce/server.php on line 21


[Mon Dec 19 00:16:03 2022] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/active-ecommerce/public/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/active-ecommerce/server.php on line 21


[Mon Dec 19 00:16:03 2022] 127.0.0.1:35764 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Mon Dec 19 00:16:10 2022] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/active-ecommerce/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/active-ecommerce/server.php on line 21


[Mon Dec 19 00:16:10 2022] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/active-ecommerce/public/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/active-ecommerce/server.php on line 21
^C
```

I don't know where to make changes is there someone who help me out on this, i will appreciate it..

below is the server.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Naft Otell <naft@laravel.com>
 */

    $uri = urldecode(
        parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
    );

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.

    if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
        return false;
    }



   require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

below is the index.php

```
<?php

ini_set('serialize_precision', -1);

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

The question is how would you solve this if it was you?

Thank you

Comment: Downvoted and voted to close as you have a similar Question open [PHP Warning: require_once Failed to open stream: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74588266/php-warning-require-once-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Please comment on the given answers and answer comments under your original question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Warning: require\_once Failed to open stream: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74588266/php-warning-require-once-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming folder doesn't have the permissions needed, try with this:

```
chown -R {username}:www-data /home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/active-ecommerce
chmod -R 750 /home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/active-ecommerce
chmod -R 770 /home/almando/Documents/laravelPro/active-ecommerce/storage
```